# Plotting average categorical data R

Tags: r

I need to plot a variable `Y` against another variable `X` which is discrete with range `(0,100)`

With the command `plot(DF$X,DF$Y)` I get this plot

[image]

but I would like to add it a line with the average values of `Y` for every `X`. Can anyone help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`?abline` should help you

```
Y <- c(1:5)
X <- c(1:5)

plot(X,Y)
abline(h=mean(Y))
```

Christof

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(DF, aes(x=factor(DF$dep_WW), y=DF$depSST_WW)) + geom_boxplot() + stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line", aes(group=1)
```

makes the trick